# Trying to get a linq subquery inside the main linq query

Tags: linq

I have a field where I'm performing a linq subquery to get the first value out of a list which works fine.

### Subquery code

```
(from tpa in TrafficPreApplications
join tpl in TrafficPixelLogs on tpa.TrafficHitId equals tpl.TrafficHitId
where tpl.PixelAmount > 0
    select tpl.PixelAmount).First()
```

I have a main linq query where I'm performing joins to get a **single row of data** (which works fine).

I would like to implement the subquery **inside** the main query where the one **tpl.PixelAmount** field gets displayed.

### Here is the main query:

```
from p in Partners
join tp in TrafficPartners on p.Id equals tp.PartnerId
join th in TrafficHits on tp.Id equals th.TrafficPartnerId
join tpa in TrafficPreApplications on th.Id equals tpa.TrafficHitId
select new { tpa.Firstname, tpa.Lastname, p.PartnerAbbrev, tp.TrafficLPPath, tp.TrafficFLPath, tpa.Laststep, tpa.DateCreated, tpa.TargetState }
```

I would like the tpl.PixelAmount field (from the subquery) to be in the same row as the rest of the fields in the main query.

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: So you want the same `PixelAmount` to be on all the rows returned?

Comment: or you want to "start" from the tpa of the row?

Comment: Yes, please :) Want the same PixelAmount to be on all the rows returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably:

```
select new { 
    tpa.Firstname, tpa.Lastname, p.PartnerAbbrev, tp.TrafficLPPath, tp.TrafficFLPath, tpa.Laststep, tpa.DateCreated, tpa.TargetState,
    PixelAmount = 
        (from tpa2 in TrafficPreApplications
         join tpl2 in TrafficPixelLogs on tpa2.TrafficHitId equals tpl2.TrafficHitId
         where tpl2.PixelAmount > 0
         select tpl2.PixelAmount).First()
}
```

instead of the `select` you are using. Note that I renamed all the various aliases you had.